# AHCI Mode for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, drivers, ssd

Sorry for making questions about Windows XP, but I have a client that still uses it and he insists not to go towards Seven, 8 or 10.

I read [some articles](http://www.prime-expert.com/articles/b02/installing-windows-xp-with-f6-ahci-raid-drivers-from-usb-only.php) about AHCI drivers to load during installation of Windows XP (F6 drivers) on a SSD drive. I already know about some problems to run SO with IDE Mode (BIOS) and the fact that XP has no AHCI driver natively.

Also, I already (have a way - second link not allowed) to wrap the correct drivers on a installation bundle using WinToFlash tool, that creates an ISO image and put F6 drivers in a way to load them when required, during text mode part of the installation.

I already (have a way - third link not allowed) to install those drivers AFTER the XP installation, updating Primary IDE Channel.

Everything is ready to start to work. But, why don't I do that?

I do not have the right F6 drivers...

I already searched many sites, including vendor ones, looking for AHCI driver to these:

- Motherboard Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. - Model H87M-D3H
- Processador Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz

No luck.

I'm not sure about AHCI Controller, if Intel(R) ICH9R/DO/DH SATA AHCI Controller, Intel(R) ICH7M/MDH SATA AHCI Controller or other else. How to know that for sure?

I tried some of those and got system hangs... Having to restore system images... It's a hard and long road.

So, I ask if someone would help me with the following:

1. How to know for sure about the correct AHCI Controller of my
   motherboard?
2. Where I can find the F6 AHCI drivers?
3. Any other advice to put those damn drivers on XP :)

Note 1: I can boot via other partition using Seven on the same machine. And, so, I can make some tests and investigations about the hardware and run diagnose tools to know that.

Note 2: I tried to put some links when I explained about how to wrap ISO bundle, but Superuser didn't allow because of my low reputation. So, there is only one link.

Comment: Why worry, many people installed even 7 under compatability or IDE mode, then switched it only when stuffing in a SSD. you just lose trim , and that would mean the disk would slow down to about 1/2 ever , as eventually it would have to delete for real, to write more again.  The user is willing to stay with the old stuff , , , so Finish the install with a only slightly crippled SSD capability, make a full system backup/clone thing, then bother to change the AHCI settings and driver then using the post install method.  If it doesnt work give-up.  I have never used the F6 driver method, too lazy

Comment: Note that your motherboard does not officially support Windows XP, only Windows 7 and 8: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4492#sp

Comment: @Psycogeek, are you saying that, for long term use of IDE compatibility mode on a SSD disk is fine? What about that deleted clusters that system cannot actually delete? Compatibility mode can reduce SSD lifetime? And trim capabilities? What specific implications I could have?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, you're rigth. Gigabyte do not support XP anymore for that motherboard. And what about generic AHCI driver? Do you know where to get generic AHCI drivers? And how to know the correct controller? Using Seven, at Device Manager I read "Intel(R) 8 Series/C220 Series SATA AHCI Controller - 8C02"

Comment: Trim does that stuff in the background, in the hardware, without it the hardware still has to do it slowly when your trying to write. I have never heard that a SSD will reduce its own lifetime by not being told to do something it would have to do eventually,  plus there are a number of people running them without knowing they should be in AHCI mode, your just expert enough to know :-)  I was mostly indicating that you could change the drivers after the fact, with the system running (somehwhat) already to test fully.  and with a backup you can error a few times while messing with it.

Comment: . . . that would be more foreward moving than trying to setup an install disk that had it all perfected in one move.  Unless your making installs for way more than the one computer.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, Psycogeek. To change drivers with the system running, here the trick: http://www.prime-expert.com/articles/a11/change-from-ide-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-xp.php. Few minutes ago I sent a request for AHCI drivers to Gigabyte Support Team. Let's listen what they say. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: [See the post by Fernando](http://www.win-raid.com/t11f23-Modded-Intel-AHCI-and-RAID-Drivers.html) he has a link to a custom generic F6 driver for the C220 controller

Comment: @Moab, your link has too many information about my question and troubles. Therefore, many pages to read and understand better AHCI subject. Thank you for the link. I'll post here the results.

Comment: @Gabarito007 The first post has the download for the hacked driver you need, either it works or does not, not much reading involved.

Comment: Downvoted for using a long-unsupported OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that it would be a good manner to answer my own question, once I already have a solution for the thread. It may helps another user in same situation.

As I said before, I sent a message to Gigabyte team asking for the drivers for my motherboard. Their reply:

> " Intel does not write drivers for Windows XP so this mobo will not
>   support XP.
>
> Thank you.
>
> Best regards, GIGABYTE Tech Support Team "

Thanks to the link provided by user Moab, I joined to Fernando's forum.
Actually, he has too many drivers and guides to tweak different needs.
Excellent forum! I recommend it.

About the solution, anyone interested about how it was solved, please read related post from [**this one**](http://www.win-raid.com/t11f23-Modded-Intel-AHCI-and-RAID-Drivers-24.html#msg16816) and foward.

Thanks.